# Image cropping issue in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, image-processing

In my asp.net C# application, I am trying to crop the below image:

[image]

I have selected only the face part, but the cropped image always selecting from top left corner like below:

[image]

I am using the below code to crop image:

```
  Rectangle sourceRect = new Rectangle(iX1, iY1, w, h);
  System.Drawing.Image imgNew = CropImage(imgOrig, sourceRect);
  private static System.Drawing.Image CropImage(System.Drawing.Image img, Rectangle    cropArea)
    {
        Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
        Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea, bmpImage.PixelFormat);
        img.Dispose();
        return (System.Drawing.Image)bmpCrop;
    }
```

Comment: The second image is cropped not from the top-left corner of the first one. And `Bitmap.Clone()` should work fine. Check your `iX1` and `iY1` values, it can be incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to crop your image.

```
static Bitmap CropImage(Image originalImage, Rectangle sourceRectangle, Rectangle destinationRectangle)
{
    var croppedImage = new Bitmap(destinationRectangle.Width, destinationRectangle.Height);
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(croppedImage))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(originalImage, destinationRectangle, sourceRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    return croppedImage;
}
```

The problem is that your original algorithm doesn't specify where to start cropping from. It therefore always starts from the origin, which is not what you want.

Comment: What is destination rectangle?

Comment: If you look at the example, you'll see that `destinationRectangle` defines the dimensions of the cropped image. `sourceRectangle` defines where to crop from. If `sourceRectangle` and `destinationRectangle` have different dimensions, the cropped image will be stretched/compressed.

Comment: Fantastic - Glad to hear it :)